# How can I forcefully change the width and height of View?

Tags: android, android-view

I am using [Alpha Movie library](https://github.com/pavelsemak/alpha-movie)

And I have two videos, The first one has longer height than width. The second one longer width than height.

When I apply the videos to the Library's custom view. The height/width ratio of the video is fixed.

I tested with this:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/assc_yellow">

            <com.alphamovie.lib.AlphaMovieView
                android:id="@+id/video_player"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                custom:accuracy="0.4"
                custom:alphaColor="#FDE958" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

The `AlphaMoiveView` must have the size of 300dp X 300dp. But didn't work.
It doesn't seem it have option for that.

I tried to change it on Activity programmatically like this:

```
alphaMovieView = findViewById(R.id.video_player)
alphaMovieView!!.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

However, It didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

just add this to the root element

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

this should work